# call setApprovalForAll of ERC721 contract from other contract fail

Tags: nft, solidity-0.8.x

I'm trying to call from MyContract the setApprovalForAll of some ERC721 contract.
When user call approveTransfer in my contract, the transaction is fail with  "code": -32603, "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC721: approve to caller". When user call setApprovalForAll directly in NFT contract, transaction succeed.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

contract MyContract {
    
    IERC721 public NftContract;

    constructor() {
        NftContract = IERC721(0x43709dE8b3e2869273C6a78418a227aC26e915bB);
    }


    function approveTransfer() public {
        NftContract.setApprovalForAll(address(this), true);
    }    
    ....
    ....
    ....

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call setApprovalForAll() on nft contract .
Because the deployer is the owner , and you try to call the function from this contract , and for this its revert because the "contract " is not the owner .
Try to call the  setApprovalForAll() from nft contract .
It should work , let me know .

Comment: Do you mean to send the transaction to NFT contract from out of my contract, for example from website by javascript?

Comment: Yes try to call it firectly from remix ( call the funtion on the NFT contract setApprovalForAll() ) and not from your contract , this should work , because you are the owner and not the contract that trying to call that function :)

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, it works when user call the function from outside the contract, like from remix. Now I understand that the call should be direct call to NFT contract. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome !